# Python syntax error. Beginner's trivia code

Tags: python, syntax-error

I wanted to create a simple program which calculates the area of a circle where method and radius are input by the user.

I am constantly getting the error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. 
What's wrong?

```
print("1 Exact | 2  π(r*r)")
choice=input()
if int(choice)>2:
print("Restart and hit 1 or 2")

if choice=="1":
pi=22/7
print("radius=...")
radius=int(input)
area=pi(radius**2)
print(area)

else: 

pi2='π'
print("radius=...")
radius2=int(input)
squareradius=int(radius2**2)
str(squareradius)
area2=pi2+squareradius
print("area2")
```

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of your code sample. If that's the way you have it in your program, it would be the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for anwser but I am afraid I don't know how should I proceed. Could you care to explain?

Comment: In addition to the wrong indentation, note that `'π'` isn't a numeric value which you can use in calculations. In order to do that, [import the `pi` constant from the `math` module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#mathematics) (or simply use `3.14` to begin with).

Comment: You should read and exercise the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: (I see you didn't intent to use `'π'` in a numeric calculation, but still are accidentally doing it, because you don't assign the result of `str(squareradius)` back to `squareradius`.)

Comment: Maybe it would help pointing out which syntax error you get. So a helping person does not need to paste that into their local enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Python indicates blocks via indentation *alone*.  Your "true" and "else" branches have to be indented.  You *cannot* indent the leading `print` statement.  Does this match your intended logic?

```
print("1 Exact | 2  π(r*r)")
choice=input()
if int(choice)>2:
    print("Restart and hit 1 or 2")

if choice=="1":

    pi=22/7
    print("radius=...")
    radius=int(input)
    area=pi(radius**2)
    print(area)

else: 

    pi2='π'
    print("radius=...")
    radius2=int(input)
    squareradius=int(radius2**2)
    str(squareradius)
    area2=pi2+squareradius
    print("area2")
```

You do have other problems, but this will get you closer to execution.  For one thing, you never print the computed value in your *else* branch -- just a literal string.

Among other things, I *strongly* recommend that you practice incremental programming: write just a line or two at a time, and don't continue until those are syntactically legal and do what you want.  Use `print` statements to trace values as you go -- and delete them later.  There is no need to get to 20 lines of code when you haven't yet managed to read in a value in the first 4 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation to define blocks of code.

This is important, as without it, there is no way for the interpreter to know what is expected to be part of that block of code.

```
if x == 5:
print ('foo')
print ('bar')
```

(Ignoring that the lack of indentation causes an error)
If `x==5` what should happen?

```
foo
bar
```

If it isn't? then what? does it print anything? does it print `bar`?

So, how does indentation fix this confusion?

Doing this:

```
if x == 5:
    print ('foo')
    print ('bar')
```

will print 
    foo
    bar
when `x==5` and nothing otherwise

```
if x == 5:
    print ('foo')
print ('bar')
```

will print

```
foo
bar
```

when `x==5` and

```
bar
```

otherwise

Comment: You shouldn't be giving advice using invalid Python syntax.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I forgot my `:`s.  fixed.